# AspectJ weaving external jar file provided by sbt throws can't determine superclass of missing type

Tags: sbt, aspectj

I'm trying to weave the testing library *scalatest* (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.2.0-SNAP10). This library dependency is in my build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(SbtAspectj)
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"

aspectjInputs in Aspectj ++= update.value.matching(moduleFilter(organization = "com.typesafe.akka", name = "akka-actor*"))
aspectjInputs in Aspectj ++= update.value.matching(moduleFilter(organization = "org.scalatest", name = "scalatest*")) 

fullClasspath in Runtime := aspectjUseInstrumentedClasses(Runtime).value ++ aspectjUseInstrumentedClasses(Test).value
```

Looking at the maven website it lists several other optional dependencies such as org.jmock, etc.

The problem is that SBT only downloads scalatest.jar and not jmock.jar (along the other optional dependencies). Printing out the `aspectjInputs` indeed does show scalatest.jar, but *not* jmock.jar.

Because of that reason (?), it gives me the following errors:

```
[error] error at (no source information available)
[error] /Users/jonas/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/bundles/scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar:0::0 can't determine superclass of missing type org.jmock.Expectations
[error] when weaving type org.scalatest.jmock.JMockExpectations
[error] when weaving classes 
[error] when weaving 
[error] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=1 AopXmls=#0
[error]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

I'm assuming that I somehow need the .jar file of the optional dependencies of ScalaTest, but as they are not downloaded by sbt, I'm lost on how to solve this.

**So, how can I resolve them or add them to the classpath when the weaving happens?**

I'm using the aspectj-sbt plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the optional dependencies with a configuration mapping like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test->compile,optional"
```

Comment: This indeed downloads the optional dependencies, but the weaving still fails with similar errors..

Comment: I tried it on a fresh project and it seems to work fine now.